# Translating VB6 Code to PHP - byte as parameter?

Tags: php, math, vb6, byte

Im working on a little project an i need to convert some vb6 code to php.
I'm at a stand still because I'm not sure how I'm supposed to be convert this set of code into PHP or even if it's possible.

This is the vb6 code

```
Private Function Ist_Bit_Gesetzt_Integer(ByVal arg As Integer, _
                                         ByVal bitpos As Byte) As Boolean
   
  If bitpos > 16 Or bitpos < 1 Then Exit Function
     
  If bitpos = 16 Then
    Ist_Bit_Gesetzt_Integer = arg < 0
  Else
    Ist_Bit_Gesetzt_Integer = arg And (2 ^ (bitpos - 1))
  End If
  
End Function
```

And this is my translated code

```
function Ist_Bit_Gesetzt($arg, $pos)
{
    if($pos > 16 || $pos < 1) 
        return false;

    if($pos == 16)
    {
        return (bool)($arg < 0);
    }else{
        return (bool)($arg && (pow(2 , ($pos - 1))));
    }
}
```

The problem is, it doesnt work as expected, and i think it's because in vb6 the parameter **bitpos** is declared as Byte.
And to be honest i also don't understand the calculation `arg And (2 ^ (bitpos - 1))`

Comment: `it doesnt work as expected`...be more specific if you can, please. What precisely did you expect and what precisely did you get instead?

Comment: Your mistake is using `&&`. You should be using `&` to perform bitwise AND, not logical AND.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function name translates to "Is Bit Set?", the purpose is to tell if the bit in the `$pos` position of `$arg` is set.

`pos(2, ($pos - 1))` is equivalent to `1 << ($pos - 1)`, it creates a number with a 1 bit in position `$pos` (counting from the right, starting from 1). This will then be used as a bit mask to combine with `$arg`; all its bits will be cleared except for the one corresponding to the 1 bit in this result.

You need to use the `&` operator to perform this bitwise masking. `&&` is a logical operation.

Converting this result to `bool` returns `true` if the number is non-zero (which will happen when the bit is set), `false` if it's zero (when the bit is not set).

So change the last line to:

```
        return (bool)($arg & (1 << ($pos - 1)));
```

Comment: Thanks now i understand it, but i dont get any result.
This is my testing code: [Example](https://i.imgur.com/h8LMRCl.png) 
Let's say, $arg is 4 and $pos is 3, it should be TRUE like in Vb6.

Comment: I had it right in the text, I made a mistake when I posted the code at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks, i posted the working function for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, this code works as expected.

```
function Ist_Bit_Gesetzt($arg, $pos)
{
    if($pos > 16 || $pos < 1) 
        return false;

    if($pos == 16)
    {
        return (bool)($arg < 0);
    }else{
        return (bool)($arg & (1 << ($pos - 1)));
    }
}
```